# How does giving query parameter "FilterId" filter the Get Sheet API response of Smartsheet API? I see no difference

Tags: smartsheet-api

I am trying to give a particular filterId with a valid value of a manually created filter on a sheet, but the response however remains the same with and without this filter.

On the UI of the sheet, filtration works exactly fine but I do not see the API response getting filtered out. Am I missing out on something? Do I need to look out for something else? Is my understanding wrong here?

[Postman response][1]

I am expecting the same cells (rows and columns) to appear in API response as well as per the filter applied using filterId.

Comment: Looks like the Postman image you tried to include in your post wasn't successfully uploaded. Can you update your post to include the `GET Sheet` requests you're issuing (with and without the filterId) and also the JSON response you're receiving for each of those requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying the `filterId` parameter in a `GET Sheet` request will not change the number of rows that the response includes. A `GET Sheet` response will always include all rows that the sheet contains, regardless of whether the `filterId` parameter is specified.

So, what *does* specifying the `filterId` parameter in a `GET Sheet` request do? It makes it so that each row in the `GET Sheet` response contains an attribute named `filteredOut` with a boolean value (`true` or `false`) to indicate the visibility of that row with the specified filter enabled.

- `"filteredOut": true` indicates that the row is ***not*** visible with the specified filter applied
- `"filteredOut": false` indicates that the row ***is*** visible with the specified filter applied

If you only want to process the rows that are visible when the specified filter is applied, your code will need to read the value of the `filteredOut` attribute for each row in the `GET Sheet` response and only process rows where that attribute value is `false`.

Finally, please note that for specifying the `filterId` to result in the behavior I've described above, the (user) account issuing the API request must have access to the filter. If another (user) account created the filter in Smartsheet and didn't make it a **shared** filter, then they are the only user (account) who will be able to access/use that filter.

Comment: Thank you again, Kim. That solved my query quick.

Comment: Happy to help, Nishika.